# mysql join query take too long to respond

Tags: mysql

I have three table in a database . for some reason I join them and use below query. it works fine

```
SELECT enduser.ncode, excel_merchant.psp_recipt_code, 
        excel_terminal.trminal_num, excel_terminal.serial, 
        excel_terminal.shop_name, excel_terminal.terminal_stat 
FROM enduser
    INNER JOIN excel_merchant on excel_merchant.reciver_ncode=enduser.ncode
    INNER JOIN excel_terminal on excel_merchant.psp_recipt_code = excel_terminal.psp_recipt_code
WHERE 1
```

but when I modify query to this:

```
SELECT enduser.ncode, excel_merchant.psp_recipt_code, 
        excel_terminal.trminal_num, excel_terminal.serial, 
        excel_terminal.shop_name, excel_terminal.terminal_stat 
FROM enduser
    INNER JOIN excel_merchant on excel_merchant.reciver_ncode=enduser.ncode
    INNER JOIN excel_terminal on excel_merchant.psp_recipt_code = excel_terminal.psp_recipt_code
WHERE excel_terminal.serial is null 
or excel_terminal.serial = ""
```

it takes too long and get no response from database nor an error.
I run query in `phpmyadmin` for remote server

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff You're kidding, right? If the double quotes are syntactically incorrect they will cause a syntax error. Not a performance problem. Your explanation for this assertion?

Comment: Its always a good idea to at least show us the schema for the tables involved in the query, then we can see if there are any indexes

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff You're kidding, right? 'Takes too long to respond' isn't a performance issue? and 'nor an error' indicates a syntax error? Really? If there was a syntax error the response would be immediate. NB I use double quotes in SQL all day long, and they don't cause eithe syntax errors or 'takes too long'.

Comment: How many rows do you get without where clause?

Comment: enuser table has about 200 rows and excel_merchant has about 15000 row and excel_terminal  has about 12000 row. when I run the query without where clause it return about 80 rows that some have empty serial column. I jus want empty serial cols.

Comment: Sigh. Provide the table definition, including the indexing if any. Otherwise your question cannot be answered. But these are not large numbers. Answer the questions you are asked here. Otherwise no soap.

Comment: I have provided very simplified tables in this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1c64b/1

Comment: @user207421 double quotes can be used to enclose identifiers and the query will raise an error in a certain configuration.

Comment: @hooman I must ask you to try using `''` instead of `""` to rule out syntax errors (or issues with PHPMyAdmin not able to handle remote errors properly). 80 rows is too little to cause timeout.

Comment: thanks for advise but there is no difference between  single quote or double quote . but i'm sure that second part in where clause (excel_terminal.serial = "") is causing the problem

Comment: @SalmanA Choice of quotes does not cause performance issues or no response.

Comment: @Moderators I am curious to know why the only comment of mine that was deleted here was the only statement in the whole thread that contained a quotation from a normative reference that refutes every assertion that has been made here about the quotation marks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try indexing  join fields.
Indexing is used to retrieve data from database very fast. It's one of the best ways to improve the performance of queries and applications.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can u please give an example. I'm not very familiar with indexing

Comment: @hooman It is you that needs to give an example. Specifically you need to provide your table definitions. If none of the items mentioned in a `WHERE` clause is indexed, that's where your problem lies. And if you're not familiar with indexing, learn about it: and this is not the place to do it.

Comment: I tried indexing the joins and it works very fast. but somewhere said indexing is affecting insert and update in negative way and make database act slower. for now i have about 20000 row and its effect for insret is not very obvious. but if it grows to milions what will happen?

Comment: That's true. Because when you are adding indexing, it creates simple structure with the indexed fields and memory allocation numbers. When you are insert, update, delete records, mysql has to do the same operating to the structure as well. So you should add indexing  when you really needed them.